# Getting Issue while taking mongodump(4.4)

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

i am getting issue while getting mongodump . i have mongodb 4.4 having ssl/Tls enabled for server side as well as for client.

but while taking dump getting the following Error:

2021-03-11T15:57:55.639+0530    Failed: can't create session: error configuring the connector: error configuring client, can't load client certificate: tls: private key type does not match public key type

although i am able to login with mongo shell.

mongo -u ms -p --authenticationDatabase "admin" --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/ca-mongo.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/host1.pem --host host1

Answer (score -1):

Add `--tlsAllowInvalidHostnames` to the command. It disables the validation of the hostnames

Full command

> mongo -u ms -p --authenticationDatabase "admin" --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/ca-mongo.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/host1.pem --host host1

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-tlsallowinvalidhostnames

If you are using version 4.2 or below then you have to use `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-tlsallowinvalidhostnames

Comment: the same has already been tried but no luck

Comment: and there is no --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames for 4.4 i tried with this :                   
  mongodump -u ms -d test --ssl --host host1 --sslCAFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/ca-mongo.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/mongodb/ssl/mongodb01.pem --tlsInsecure